# How to handle a hierarchy of traits & generics for a function implementation?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I'm looking to implement a situation similar to the following - in an attempt to reduce code duplication. I only want a single implementation of the `read_section` method, which can handle all potential types of Piece.

I think I'm missing some concepts around traits and generics to do it properly so help is appreciated.

```rust
trait ReadSection {
    fn read_section(&mut self, section: &mut impl Section);
}

trait PieceHandler {
    type PieceType;
    fn new(capacity: Option<u16>) -> Self;
    fn read(&mut self, reader: Box<dyn BufRead>);
}

trait Section {
    type PieceType;
    fn new(size: Option<u16>) -> Self;
    fn get(&self) -> Vec<&PuzzlePiece<Self::SectionType>>;
}

struct Section<T>(Vec<Piece<T>>)
struct Piece<T>(Vec<T>)

impl ReadSection for Box<dyn BufRead> {
    fn read_section(&mut self, section: &mut impl Section) {
        for piece in section.get().iter_mut() {
            piece.read(self); // issue exists here**
        }
    }
}
```

The problem that exists is that I can't guarantee that `piece` implements the read function for a type , which I sort of understand. I don't want to have to write this `read_section` function for each piece of type  when I know that they have valid implementations of the read function that will work in the way I need.

#### Questions

- Is there any concepts here I'm missing?
- Are trait hierarchy's in the function impl a thing? `Section.get() impl PieceHandler<T>` ?? (this seems wrong but maybe im on the right track?
- Am I thinking about a solution in the wrong way?
- Is there a way I can build this current setup out so that only a single implementation of ReadSection is required despite having various types for pieces?

Comment: Possibly relevant: https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html#using-trait-bounds-to-conditionally-implement-methods

Comment: Also note that you have `struct Section<T>(Vec<Piece<T>>)` and `struct Piece<T>(Vec<T>)` that means you effectively have a `Vec<Vec <T>>` here, which I don't think is what you're looping through correctly, but you _may_ be, depending on your intention.  So be careful.

Comment: @KevinAnderson the read method on Piece<T>, implemented through PieceHandler, is intended to loop across that. Small implementation detail I left out.

Comment: If you're defining [associated types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/generics/assoc_items/types.html) in a trait, you should be referencing them at least once (both `PieceHandler` and `Section`). Also, you can and probably should avoid `Box<dyn Trait>` and `impl` in your signatures here for maximum flexibility. Instead, add another type variable with trait bounds. E.g. `impl<R: BufRead> ReadSection for R {}`.

Comment: Scratch that last bit: `impl<R: BufRead> ReadSection for R {}` is not the right way to express this. What you probably want is a trait bound on the `ReadSection` trait itself: `trait ReadSection: BufRead {}`

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the code you currently have. Where does `Self::SectionType` come from? What is `PuzzlePiece`? Did you mean `fn get(&self) -> Vec<&Piece<Self::PieceType>>`? Why is `Section` both a trait and a struct? What's the point of `PieceHandler`; it gets used nowhere? I know you say *"issue exists here"*, but please provide an example where the issue actually exists there and not everywhere else, I'd love to help you but I'm having a really hard time understanding what's going on.